# Using tHashOutput and tHashInput in Talend esb

Tags: esb, talend

I am trying to merge two responses using tHashOutput -> tHashInput, so firstly I am trying to use it for simple, straightforward job and it doesn't work. I send via Soap UI request with ID, then based on this ID retrive name from DB and show it as result. Data are inserted into hashOutput, but aren't there in hashInput.

WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="customerSoap"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.talend.org/service/"
    targetNamespace="http://www.talend.org/service/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.talend.org/service/">
      <s:element name="getCustomer">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element name="customerId" type="s:integer"/>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="getCustomerResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element name="getCustomerResult" type="s:string"/>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="getCustomerName">
        <s:complexType>
            <s:sequence>
                <s:element name="customerId" type="s:integer"></s:element>
            </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="getCustomerNameResponse">
        <s:complexType>
            <s:sequence>
                <s:element name="customerNameResult" type="s:string"></s:element>
            </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
  <s:element name="getCustomerAddress">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element name="customerId" type="s:integer"></s:element>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="getCustomerAddressResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element name="customerAddressResult" type="s:string"></s:element>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="getCustomerRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getCustomer" name="parameters"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getCustomerResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getCustomerResponse" name="parameters"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getCustomerNameRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getCustomerName"></wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getCustomerNameResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getCustomerNameResponse"></wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getCustomerAddressRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getCustomerAddress"></wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getCustomerAddressResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getCustomerAddressResponse"></wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="customerSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="getCustomer">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:getCustomerRequest"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:getCustomerResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getCustomerName">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:getCustomerNameRequest"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:getCustomerNameResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getCustomerAddress">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:getCustomerAddressRequest"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:getCustomerAddressResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="customerSoap" type="tns:customerSoap">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="getCustomer">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.talend.org/service/getCustomer" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getCustomerName">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.talend.org/service/getCustomer" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getCustomerAddress">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.talend.org/service/getCustomer" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="airport">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:customerSoap" name="customerSoap">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8090/esb/customerSoap"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Exception:

```
Starting job customerSoap_getCustomerName at 10:31 31/03/2016.

[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3524
[statistics] connected
mar 31, 2016 10:31:04 AM org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromWSDL
INFO: Creating Service {http://www.talend.org/service/}airport from WSDL: C:/Users/VKAROL/Downloads/TESB/Studio/workspace/FINAL10/services/customerSoap_0.1.wsdl
mar 31, 2016 10:31:05 AM org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl initDestination
INFO: Setting the server's publish address to be http://localhost:8090/esb/customerSoap
2016-03-31 10:31:05.163:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
2016-03-31 10:31:05.221:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@localhost:8090
web service [endpoint: http://localhost:8090/esb/customerSoap] published
mar 31, 2016 10:31:08 AM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://www.talend.org/service/}airport#{http://www.talend.org/service/}getCustomerName has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not generate the XML stream caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [2,0].
    at org.apache.cxf.databinding.source.XMLStreamDataWriter.write(XMLStreamDataWriter.java:94)
    at org.apache.cxf.databinding.source.XMLStreamDataWriter.write(XMLStreamDataWriter.java:54)
    at org.apache.cxf.databinding.source.XMLStreamDataWriter.write(XMLStreamDataWriter.java:48)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.BareOutInterceptor.handleMessage(BareOutInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1088)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1024)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [2,0]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:685)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleEOF(BasicStreamReader.java:2141)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2047)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1131)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.copy(StaxUtils.java:771)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.copy(StaxUtils.java:701)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.copy(StaxUtils.java:625)
    at org.apache.cxf.databinding.source.XMLStreamDataWriter.write(XMLStreamDataWriter.java:91)
    ... 28 more
```

Here is how my job looks like:
[image]

My tXMLMap:
[image]

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from Shong from Talend Team on official forum:

Hi
I think this is because 'keep listening' box is checked on tESBRequestProvider, tHashInput linked with onsubjobOK will never work. To resolve it, change the job design to:
tESBRequestProvider.....tHashOutput--oncomponentok-tHashInput--main--tESBResponseProvider
Regards
Shong